# Publishing an npm package

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts, npm-publish, npm-package

How to use .ENV variables when publishing npm package.
Is there any way to publish my npm package in any way with .env-variable?

Thank you in advance!

```
And i am using this version: "dotenv": "^16.0.3"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a confused. The `.env` always will be created by the consumer of your lib. He will create a `.env` file and set the values. What you must is added the env variables in your documentation.

By the way, the `.env` file usually doesn't commit to your repo. But you can commit a file template like `.env.template` to help other developers to use your lib.